# condition show - hide products - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to create an if condition, the function would be to hide or show products depending on whether it is visible or not

visible: 1
hidden: 0

The table is already created, as you can see, I only need the code
[image]

**my code: blade.php**

```
     <div style="margin-top: 10px; "  class="w-100">

  @if(count($products)>0)
      @php
      $total = 0;
      @endphp

      @foreach($products as $product)
        @php 
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $product_q = 0;

        if ($cart) {
          foreach ($cart as $item) {
            if ($item->id == $product->id) {
              $product_q = $item->quantity ?? 0;
              $total = $total + ($product->price * $item->quantity);
            }
          }
        }

        if (is_numeric($product_q) == false) {
          $product_q = 0;
        }
        @endphp
      
     
        <div class="bg-dark tx-white h-100">
      
            <ul class="list-group bordecero">
          
              <li class="list-group-item bordecero bg-dark tx-white w-100">
                <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                  @if($category->show_img)
                  <div class="col-4">
                    
                    @if(!empty($product->image))
                    <img style="height: auto;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img-fluid" src="{{ url($product->image) }}">
                    @else
                    <img style="height: auto;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/700x400">
                    @endif
                    
                  </div>
                  @endif
                  <div class="@if($category->show_img) col-8 @else col-12 @endif">
                    <h5>  <a style="color: #fff;"   href="{{ route('product-detail',['slug'=> $product->slug]) }}">{{$product->name}}</a><span class="badge badge-pill badge-light tx-dark ml-2 product-count-{{$product->id}}">{{$product_q}}</span>
                   
                    </h5>
       
       
                      <h6>
                        <span style="color: #fff;" class="label label-success">${{ number_format($product->price,2) }}</span>
                      </h6>

                      <p style="color: #fff;">{{$product->description}}</p>



                      @if($product->destacado)
                      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger ">DESTACADO</span>
                      @endif
                      @php 
                      $extras = App\Extra::where("product_id", $product->id)->first();
                      @endphp
                       @if(!empty($extras))
                       <a style="color: #2c2c2c;"   href="{{ route('product-detail',['slug'=> $product->slug]) }}"> 
                         <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mb-4  ">+ AGREGADOS</span>
                       </a>
                       @else
                       <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary   mb-4">SIN AGREGADOS</span>
                       @endif

                   
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex">
                      <input type="hidden" id="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-slug="{{$product->slug}}" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="form-control select2 quantity" name="num_entregable" @if(isset($product_q)) value="{{$product_q}}" @else value="1" @endif min="1" required>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2 quantity-modify" data-quantity="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-modify="add"> <b><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></b></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger quantity-modify" data-quantity="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-modify="remove"> <b><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></b></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
           
              </ul>
       
       
        </div>
   
   
      
     
      @endforeach
     
      <div style="z-index: 100;" class="pedidob mg-t-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-block tx-white d-flex justify-content-center" href="{{url('/cart/show')}}"><b>VER PEDIDO -    <span class="total">{{$total}}</span>$</b></a>
      </div> 
       </div>
       
  @else
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">No hay productos</a>
          </h4>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  @endif
```

I need to create an if condition to show or hide the products according to the 'visible' table

help pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write condition @if($product->visible == 1) just after the foreach, to exclude the products that are set to hidden, you can tryout below code

```
  <div style="margin-top: 10px; "  class="w-100">

  @if(count($products)>0)
      @php
      $total = 0;
      @endphp

      @foreach($products as $product)
        @if($product->visible == 1)
        @php 
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $product_q = 0;

        if ($cart) {
          foreach ($cart as $item) {
            if ($item->id == $product->id) {
              $product_q = $item->quantity ?? 0;
              $total = $total + ($product->price * $item->quantity);
            }
          }
        }

        if (is_numeric($product_q) == false) {
          $product_q = 0;
        }
        @endphp
      
     
        <div class="bg-dark tx-white h-100">
      
            <ul class="list-group bordecero">
          
              <li class="list-group-item bordecero bg-dark tx-white w-100">
                <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                  @if($category->show_img)
                  <div class="col-4">
                    
                    @if(!empty($product->image))
                    <img style="height: auto;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img-fluid" src="{{ url($product->image) }}">
                    @else
                    <img style="height: auto;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/700x400">
                    @endif
                    
                  </div>
                  @endif
                  <div class="@if($category->show_img) col-8 @else col-12 @endif">
                    <h5>  <a style="color: #fff;"   href="{{ route('product-detail',['slug'=> $product->slug]) }}">{{$product->name}}</a><span class="badge badge-pill badge-light tx-dark ml-2 product-count-{{$product->id}}">{{$product_q}}</span>
                   
                    </h5>
       
       
                      <h6>
                        <span style="color: #fff;" class="label label-success">${{ number_format($product->price,2) }}</span>
                      </h6>

                      <p style="color: #fff;">{{$product->description}}</p>



                      @if($product->destacado)
                      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger ">DESTACADO</span>
                      @endif
                      @php 
                      $extras = App\Extra::where("product_id", $product->id)->first();
                      @endphp
                       @if(!empty($extras))
                       <a style="color: #2c2c2c;"   href="{{ route('product-detail',['slug'=> $product->slug]) }}"> 
                         <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mb-4  ">+ AGREGADOS</span>
                       </a>
                       @else
                       <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary   mb-4">SIN AGREGADOS</span>
                       @endif

                   
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex">
                      <input type="hidden" id="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-slug="{{$product->slug}}" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="form-control select2 quantity" name="num_entregable" @if(isset($product_q)) value="{{$product_q}}" @else value="1" @endif min="1" required>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2 quantity-modify" data-quantity="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-modify="add"> <b><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></b></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger quantity-modify" data-quantity="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-modify="remove"> <b><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></b></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
           
              </ul>
       
       
        </div>
   
   
      
      @endif
      @endforeach
     
      <div style="z-index: 100;" class="pedidob mg-t-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-block tx-white d-flex justify-content-center" href="{{url('/cart/show')}}"><b>VER PEDIDO -    <span class="total">{{$total}}</span>$</b></a>
      </div> 
       </div>
       
  @else
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">No hay productos</a>
          </h4>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```php
<div style="margin-top: 10px; " class="w-100">

    @if(count($products)>0)
    @php
    $total = 0;
    @endphp

    @foreach($products as $product)
    @php
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $product_q = 0;

    if ($cart) {
    foreach ($cart as $item) {
    if ($item->id == $product->id) {
    $product_q = $item->quantity ?? 0;
    $total = $total + ($product->price * $item->quantity);
    }
    }
    }

    if (is_numeric($product_q) == false) {
    $product_q = 0;
    }
    @endphp
    @if($product->visible)
    <div class="bg-dark tx-white h-100">

        <ul class="list-group bordecero">

            <li class="list-group-item bordecero bg-dark tx-white w-100">
                <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    @if($category->show_img)
                    <div class="col-4">

                        @if(!empty($product->image))
                        <img style="height: auto;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img-fluid"
                            src="{{ url($product->image) }}">
                        @else
                        <img style="height: auto;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img-fluid"
                            src="http://placehold.it/700x400">
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="@if($category->show_img) col-8 @else col-12 @endif">
                        <h5> <a style="color: #fff;"
                                href="{{ route('product-detail',['slug'=> $product->slug]) }}">{{$product->name}}</a><span
                                class="badge badge-pill badge-light tx-dark ml-2 product-count-{{$product->id}}">{{$product_q}}</span>

                        </h5>


                        <h6>
                            <span style="color: #fff;" class="label label-success">${{ number_format($product->price,2)
                                }}</span>
                        </h6>

                        <p style="color: #fff;">{{$product->description}}</p>



                        @if($product->destacado)
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger ">DESTACADO</span>
                        @endif
                        @php
                        $extras = App\Extra::where("product_id", $product->id)->first();
                        @endphp
                        @if(!empty($extras))
                        <a style="color: #2c2c2c;" href="{{ route('product-detail',['slug'=> $product->slug]) }}">
                            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mb-4  ">+ AGREGADOS</span>
                        </a>
                        @else
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary   mb-4">SIN AGREGADOS</span>
                        @endif


                        <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex">
                            <input type="hidden" id="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-slug="{{$product->slug}}"
                                data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="form-control select2 quantity" name="num_entregable"
                                @if(isset($product_q)) value="{{$product_q}}" @else value="1" @endif min="1" required>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2 quantity-modify"
                                data-quantity="quantity-{{$product->id}}" data-modify="add"> <b><i
                                        class="fas fa-plus"></i></b></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger quantity-modify" data-quantity="quantity-{{$product->id}}"
                                data-modify="remove"> <b><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></b></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>


    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach

    <div style="z-index: 100;" class="pedidob mg-t-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-block tx-white d-flex justify-content-center"
            href="{{url('/cart/show')}}"><b>VER PEDIDO - <span class="total">{{$total}}</span>$</b></a>
    </div>
</div>

@else
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
                <a href="#">No hay productos</a>
            </h4>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endif
```